# What is an 'end-of-the-pier entertainment'?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, british-english

Reading "Nothing To Be Frightened Of" by Julian Barnes I found this phrase. This is the full paragraph.

> If there were a games-playing God, He would surely get especial ludic
>   pleasure from disappointing those philosophers who had convinced
>   themselves and others of his nonexistence. A.J. Ayer assures Somerset
>   Maugham that there is nothing, and nothingness, after death: whereupon
>   they both find themselves players in God’s little **end-of-the-pier
>   entertainment** called Watch the Fury of the Resurrected Atheist. That’s
>   a neat little would-you-rather for the God-denying philosopher: would
>   you rather there was nothing after death, and you were proved right,
>   or that there was a wonderful surprise, and your professional
>   reputation was destroyed?

What kind of amusement do you enjoy at the end of a pier? The hyphens tells me that there is hidden something more. Is this something like a reality show kind of 'Big Brother'?

Comment: See http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/theatre/10174045/The-end-of-the-end-of-the-pier-show.html and http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/3XGRLLWdrvGfhP9pk3RKkpZ/about-the-end-of-the-pier-show for example.

Comment: Gosh, I tried to explain this hyphenated adjectival use and got shot down: would-you-rather for the God-denying philosopher. This is a great example of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting during Victorian times in Britain it became very popular for people to go to the [seaside for holidays](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/british/victorians/seaside_01.shtml).

Many seaside resorts built piers on which tourists could walk to take the sea air, which was said to be good for the health.  Certainly better than the smoky city air of the time.

Small theatres were typically built at the ends of piers to provide entertainment.  This was usually in the form of a variety show, not unlike the Music Halls found in cities.  The intention was to provide cheap, light entertainment.

The end-of-the-pier show became a tradition.

As holidays have moved on, the end-of-the-pier show and the piers themselves have become much less popular.

Various attempts have been made to [preserve them](http://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/theatre/477955/Roy-Hudd-on-end-of-Cromer-Pier-Show) and there are a few still in existence, e.g. [this one in Cromer (Norfolk)](http://www.cromerpier.co.uk/cromer-pier-show/).

So, the expression *End of the pier show* just refers to any light entertainment that is intended for pure amusement.

Comment: More specifically, it's usually (and certainly in the case of OP's citation) a *derogatory* label meaning "downmarket" entertainment. Typified by those painted backdrop screens with oval holes where unsophisticated holidaymakers stick their heads through to be photographed. Slightly odd when one considers that the specific theme addressed by the writer is in fact a fairly knotty philosophical problem (but the writer affects to consider [Pascal's wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Wager) a "trivial" issue).

Comment: So this is the origin of the phrase but what an 'end-of-the-pier' synonym would be? 'Camp', 'cheesy', 'kitsch'?